# Add foreign key in MariaDB server

Tags: mysql, express

Using expressJS mysql module, I was able to create simple database table. But when I tried alter table with add constraint foreign key, I got syntax error.

**SCRIPT.JS**

```
connection.query('\
ALTER TABLE `' + dbconfig.database + '`.`' + dbconfig.menu_table + '` ( \
ADD CONSTRAINT `caterer_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `mydatabase.item` (`id`) \
)');
```

**ERROR**

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(     ADD CONSTRAINT caterer_fk FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `mydatabase.item`' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's

```
  ALTER TABLE db.table ADD CONSTRAINT whatever
```

not

```
  ALTER TABLE db.table ( ADD CONSTRAINT whatever )   /* wrong! */
```

MySQL and MariaDB syntax error messages display the statement starting with the first character the parser didn't understand.